# Using pselect for synchronous wait

Tags: c++, c, sockets, posix

In a server code I want to use pselect to wait for clients to connect as well monitor the standard output of the prozesses that I create and send it to the client (like a simplified remote shell).

I tried to find examples on how to use pselect but I haven't found any. The socket where the client can connect is already set up and works, as I verified that with accept(). SIGTERM is blocked.

Here is the code where I try to use pselect:

```
waitClient()
{
    fd_set readers;
    fd_set writers;
    fd_set exceptions;
    struct timespec ts;

    // Loop until we get a sigterm to shutdown
    while(getSigTERM() == false)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readers);
        FD_ZERO(&writers);
        FD_ZERO(&exceptions);

        FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readers);
        FD_SET(fileno(stdout), &writers);
        FD_SET(fileno(stderr), &writers);
        FD_SET(getServerSocket()->getSocketId(), &readers);
        //FD_SET(getServerSocket()->getSocketId(), &writers);

        memset(&ts, 0, sizeof(struct timespec));
        pret = pselect(FD_SETSIZE, &readers, &writers, &exceptions, &ts, &mSignalMask);

        // Here pselect always returns with 2. What does this mean?
        cout << "pselect returned..." << pret << endl;
        cout.flush();
}
}
```

So what I want to know is how to wait with pselect until an event is received, because currently pselect always returns immediately with a value 2. I tried to set the timeout to NULL but that doesn't change anything.

The returnvalue of pselect (if positive) is the filedescriptor that caused the event?

I'm using fork() to create new prozesses (not implemented yet) I know that I have to wait() on them. Can I wait on them as well? I suppose I need to chatch the signal SIGCHILD, so how would I use that? wait() on the child would also block, or can I just do a peek and then continue with pselect, otherwise I have to concurrent blocking waits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns immediately because the file descriptors in the `writers` set are ready. The standard output streams will almost always be ready for writing.

And if you check a [`select` manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html) you will see that the return value is either `-1` on error, `0` on timeout, and a positive number telling you the number of file descriptors that are ready.

Comment: So it doesn't make sense to wait on the writers anyway? Or only for the writers on a socket?

Comment: @Devolus Unless you send large amount of data on the sockets, it's very unlikely the write-calls will block. I found it's not really no use to have a write-set in most cases, as the descriptors in it will mostly be ready anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I was googling yesterday the whole day but I didn't find the descriptions very clear.

Comment: The manpage is not really helpfull because the code doesn't work with FD_ISSET as it is supposed to be.